# Parsing outlook email strings, need just angle bracket text smtp address

Tags: perl

I have a string

```
Casperfoo DataOps <casperf@domain .com>;Booya Support <iptsupport@domain .com>; Tripped Support <Tsupport@domain capital.com>; Smith, Joe: IB Reference Data (NYK) <joe.smith@domain .com>; Johnson, Walter: IB Reference Data (PUN) <walter.johnson@domain .com>;
```

and I'd expect this to work

```
cat  /tmp/foo | perl -nle 'print /\<(\w+)\>/'
```

but it does not. 
All I want is the string between the < and the >. I don't need the crappy outlook aliases - just the smtp addresses.

This is the expected output

```
casperf@domain.com 
iptsupport@domain.com 
Tsupport@domaincapital.com  
joe.smith@domain.com 
walter.johnson@domain.com
```

Comment: $ cat  /tmp/foo | perl -nle 'print /\<(\w+@\w+)\>/'  - not working

Comment: Note: that `cat` is unneeded, can just do `perl -nle'...' /tmp/foo`

Answer (score 3):

> and I'd expect this to work

Then your expectations are wrong :-) Perhaps you'd get closer if you read [the regex documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (or [the tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)).

Some problems:

1. You match with `\w+`. The escape sequence `\w` matches letters, numbers and the underscore. Email addresses contain other characters (for example, `@`) so this matches nothing. Let's replace `\w+` with `\S+` (to match all non-whitespace characters).
2. That still doesn't work, as your email addresses all seem to contain a space (e.g. `<casperf@domain .com>`). Ok, so let's use `<.+>` instead to match anything, but add `?` to force a minimal match - `<.+?>`.
3. That just gives us the first match, because that's what we're asking for. We need to add `/g` to the match operator to get all matches.

We now have:

```
$ cat  /tmp/foo | perl -nle 'print /\<(.+?)\>/g
```

Which gives us:

```
casperf@domain .comiptsupport@domain .comTsupport@domain capital.comjoe.smith@domain .comwalter.johnson@domain .com
```

So we get all of the matches, but they're all on the same line. The easiest fix is to put the match in a postfix `for` loop so `print()` gets the matches one at a time:

```
$ cat  /tmp/foo | perl -nle 'print for /\<(.+?)\>/g'
casperf@domain .com
iptsupport@domain .com
Tsupport@domain capital.com
joe.smith@domain .com
walter.johnson@domain .com
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `<` and `>`, do you?

Comment: @JimDavis: No, you don't. I was just making minimal changes to the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat /tmp/foo | perl -nle 'while (/<([^>]+)>/g){ print $1; }'
```

It should work. Tried it with

```
echo "Casperfoo DataOps <casperf@domain .com>;Booya Support <iptsupport@domain .com>; Tripped Support <Tsupport@domain capital.com>; Smith, Joe: IB Reference Data (NYK) <joe.smith@domain .com>; Johnson, Walter: IB Reference Data (PUN) <walter.johnson@domain .com>;" | perl -nle 'while (/<([^>]+)>/g){ print $1; }'
```

which gave me:

```
casperf@domain .com
iptsupport@domain .com
Tsupport@domain capital.com
joe.smith@domain .com
walter.johnson@domain .com
```

Comment: Can also do `print $1 while /.../`, or `print for /.../` (just cosmetics really)